# Passing field name as an argument to a method in the same class in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

```
public class ConstructorA {
  private String FieldA, FieldB, FieldC;
  public String Setter(String ArgAA, String ArgAB) {
      this.ArgAA = ArgAB;  //or ArgAA could include "this."
  }
  public String Getter(String ArgBA) {
      return ArgBA;
  }
ObjectA = new ConstructorA();
ObjectA.Setter(FieldA, "TextA");
ObjectA.Setter(FieldB, "TextB");
ObjectA.Setter(FieldC, "TextC");
System.out.printf("%s %s %s", ObjectA.Getter(FieldA), ObjectA.Getter(FieldB), ObjectA.Getter(FieldC));
```

I'm trying to create generic setter and getter (mutator and accessor) methods that would be able to assign and retrieve values to and from fields without a specific pair of such methods for each individual field, by passing the name of the field as an argument into the method pair. This is partly due to curiosity, but also to reduce boilerplate code for cases where objects have a lot of fields, each with its own getter/setter. The code I'm making has been abstracted in the above snippet to show what exactly I wish to accomplish. If any extra detail or clarification is needed or anything seems ambiguous, please don't hesitate to ask.

I understand the code above is rather ridiculous and likely resembles pseudocode more than java, since the above would not work at all, I think. But is anything remotely similar to the above possible? I'm new to Java and so not very familiar with its features and limitations. I understand something similar would be possible in C, using pointers?

Anyhow, sorry for the lengthy text, and thanks in advance! Any input is valuable and much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.

If a class has many getters,  it is badly designed.

You are essentially treating an object as a `Map` of names to values. Perhaps your use case is *actually* that you need a `Map` from names to values?

Comment: Thanks! This is the first time I've heard of `Map`! It looks interesting, but it can only store two values, a key and value pair, right? Would it be possible to put an array of strings as the value in a hexmap such that it acts as a table and the keys act as primary key for rows? Thus each 'row' could simulate an instance of the object currently implemented, which stores multiple strings?

Comment: But iterating over it needs to convert it to a set, which doesn't allow for duplicate values, right? So `((StringA != StringB) && (StringB != StringC) && (StringC != StringA))` if accessing it in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with @Raedwald that too many fields can suggest a possibly design deficiency. That said, there are easier alternatives to reducing code rather than accessing fields via reflection as your post suggests.

One alternative is to add a library like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), which inject code during compile time if special annotations are applied to fields, classes, methods, etc.

For example the `@lombok.Data` annotation will create getters, setters, toString, constructors, hashcode and equals automatically for you. eg

```
@lombok.Data
public class LargePojo {
    private String a;
    private int b;
    private List<String> c;
}
```

You can then access the field `a` like this:

```
largePojo.getA()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for the purposes of this project, I'm not allowed to use external libraries. It seems really interesting and viable though! In my research, I did come across the term reflection several times. How would that work?

Comment: @Terrornado The reflection API's let you dynamically examine the structure of a `Class`. You can determine fields, methods, and lots of other information regarding how your class was written. These API's can be used to write some pretty hacky code as they can enable you to modify objects in ways the author of a class did not intend. I would not advise using reflection at this point. It can slow down your code greatly and be prone to error if not used carefully. If I were in your shoes I would take the hit and write the class in a normal style, even if there is extra boiler plate code.